# How can I include a variable in a vector in R?

Tags: r, loops, variables

In a loop, I want to insert "i" into a vector. How can I do that?

I tried the following code:

```
m1nash.best.response.coordinates<- NULL
for (i in 1:2) {
  if(m1nash[1,i]>m1nash[2,i]) {
    m1nash.best.response.coordinates <- c(m1nash.best.response.coordinates, 1,i)
  } if(m1nash[2,i]>m1nash[1,i]) {
    m1nash.best.response.coordinates <- c(m1nash.best.response.coordinates, 2, i)
  }

}
```

Came across the following console:

```
Error: unexpected 'if' in:
"    m1nash.best.response.coordinates <- c(m1nash.best.response.coordinates, 1,i)
  } if"
>     m1nash.best.response.coordinates <- c(m1nash.best.response.coordinates, 2, i)
Error: object 'i' not found
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: In R, statements are delimited by newline, and only a single statement can appear in a line (except if separated by semicolon — but don’t do this). Hence the error.

Comment: Curious, what if *m1nash*? And why only `1:2`? You may not need any loop.

Comment: I intended to write such a code that used generalizable technology (loops) on a small example (a 2*2 payoff matrix).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
m1nash.best.response.coordinates<- NULL
for (i in 1:2) {
  if (m1nash[1,i]>m1nash[2,i]) {
    m1nash.best.response.coordinates <- c(m1nash.best.response.coordinates, 1,i)
  } 
  if (m1nash[2,i]>m1nash[1,i]) {
    m1nash.best.response.coordinates <- c(m1nash.best.response.coordinates, 2, i)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Kaan,

There's a couple best practice choices you should be making, including whether the `for` loop or `if` statement are the best choices.

However, if all you are worried about is getting your code to work. There a couple things you could do.

I would prefer to initialize `m1nash.best.response.coordinates` as an empty vector instead of `NULL`. If can do so by assigning it as `c()`

Secondly, I believe you have a spelling mistake on this line `if(m1nash[2,i]>m1nas[1,i])`. `m1nas` should be `m1nash`.

You can try this loop below

```
m1nash.best.response.coordinates <- c()
m1nash <- matrix(data = rnorm(4), nrow=2, ncol=2) #my test matrix

for (i in 1:2) {
  if (m1nash[1, i] > m1nash[2, i]) {
    m1nash.best.response.coordinates <-
      c(m1nash.best.response.coordinates, 1, i)
  }
  if (m1nash[2, i] > m1nash[1, i]) {
    m1nash.best.response.coordinates <-
      c(m1nash.best.response.coordinates, 2, i)
  }

}
```

You do not answer the condition if `m1nash[1,i]= m1nash[2,i]`. If this is not possible, perhaps even use the `ifelse` function if you want to stay with the `if` family.

Good luck

Comment: In R, “empty vector” and `NULL` are almost interchangeable. It’s absolutely not important to initialise with `c()` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: I thought I edited the spelling mistake, but thanks for pointing it out anyway. The only difference between our loops was that you put the second if statement on a separate line than }. When I amended likewise, the code worked. Will now focus on the part where the two columns are equal. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yeah, I think it was a force of habit, but @KonradRudolph hit the nail on the head with the newline comment. That's the main thing. If you plan on running a similar type of code for a larger matrix or a larger loop, you may have to redesign your entire process. Right now that code will be very inefficient once you start to scale. Good luck!

Comment: @RobeleBaker In the beginning I like to demonstrate my thinking on smaller examples and scale afterwards. But you seem to have a point anyway.